# send text from a php file to a variable in html

Tags: php, html

Can i send text from a php file into a variable in an html file? I have an if statement in my php, that checks if a field is empty. If it is empty then i want to send to my html file a text saying 'please fill the field' and put it in a label in my html. Is there a way for that?

```
<?php 

$name = $_REQUEST['author'];
$from = $_REQUEST['email'];
$subj = $_REQUEST['sub'];
$message = $_REQUEST['msg'];
$subject = $subj;
$body = $message;
$headers .= "From: ".$from;

$to = "mail@mail.com";

if ($name = ''){
     HERE i want to send a text to a variable named 'reason' in my html in case $name is empty.
    }

if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)) {
    header( "Location: http://www.mysite.com/contactForm-english" );
    } else {
echo "There was a problem sending the mail. Check your code and make sure that the e-mail address ".$to." is valid";
}

?>
```

Comment: use `jquery validation` instead.

Comment: You may send an AJAX request and get response on your conditions.

Comment: Yogesh, relying entirely on jQuery validation is bad. OP is doing the right thing by checking it server side, however jQuery validation is great for user-friendliness, however; You still need to make sure you check the data server side.

Comment: @DavidHarris I am totally agree with you. :)

Comment: can we see your CODEs please?

Comment: i added the code of the php

Comment: dude, sending data from php to html is the real issue for you here. so i prefer jquery ajax calls.

Comment: send data via ajax (use jquery.ajax()). parse it for validation. return a text value which is the variable for you. set it as the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo $variable; ?>
```

Comment: is this possible in sending data from php to html?

Comment: It's much easier with php, but if you want to do a html version, read up on this. http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5442

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll just echo out the HTML like any other ordinary echo.

```
echo '<label>Test</label>';
```

It can be embed right in your HTML (as long it's a PHP file, obviously) like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php echo $something === true ? '<label>test</label>' : ''; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cant i use it in my php and send the value from there? 
like echo $variableNameInHtml "the message to put in the vaiable" 
psudocode lets say:P

Comment: Oh wait, I see what you mean now. No, you cannot. PHP is not in control of the HTML, it can only output it and nothing more. You can consider using jQuery to make an AJAX request to your script which returns JSON or something and decode it then use that.

Comment: i dont think this answer is relevant to the question asked